# How to check values in dictionary with multiple data

Tags: python, list, sorting, key, robotframework

How to find a particular value if the list contains more than one set of data.

Example:

[{u'first_name': u'a, u'last_name': u'ab'}, { u'first_name': u'c', u'last_name': u'cd',}]

This is the response i get when i do a get to a json.

I want to check that user "a" (first name) is the person who has "ab" as last name.However the order of appearance will not always be the same.

I am writing this code in python/robot framework.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Please clarify. What output do you expect if you have _two_ user "a"s, and only one of them has last name "ab"? What if more than one has last name "ab"? What if none of them do? What if there are no user "a"s?

Comment: That's a list, not a dictionary. Hence, check each item in the list.

Comment: I need to update one of the users names and check the correct name has been updated, however new names may also be added so i cannot confirm the order. I want to check the value of "u'first_name'" is C. but i want to make sure it is for the { u'first_name': u'c', u'last_name': u'cd',} user

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you are wanting to check if certain a last name has been updated to the correct first name. Since the order is unknown, and first names may be changed, it must also be necessary that last names are unique. If you must use a list of dictionaries for this you will need to loop through:

```
userlist = [{u'first_name': u'a', u'last_name': u'ab'}, 
            {u'first_name': u'c', u'last_name': u'cd',}]

for user in userlist:
    if user['last_name'] == 'cd':
       if user['first_name'] == 'c':
           print "correct first name"
       else:
           print "incorrect first name"
```

However, if you have unique last names, then it would be more efficient to just store users as a dictionary, with last names as keys and first names as values:

```
if userdict['cd'] == 'c':
    print "correct first name"
else:
    print "incorrect first name"
```

Comment: This does not work as it does not recognise the 'last_name' for a list. The error i receive is that the value must be an integer

Comment: `last_name` is not a list, it's a dictionary key. The above code works for me, given your example data. You will need to elaborate more on how you are getting such an error - how are you using `last_name`?